# Protractor: Two drop down menus on the same page, can only successfully select element from one dropdown menu

Tags: node.js, jasmine, protractor, angularjs-e2e, e2e-testing

I'm using Protractor to run an automated script, on one of the pages there are two drop down menus that are located below/above each other. The two of them seem identical only that they have different ng-model names etc. I can sucessfully select an element from one of the drop down menus but I can't for the other. It's kind of wrecking my head as to why one works and the other doesn't. Here is the code for the drop down menu where I can select an element

```html
<select class="form-control ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-invalid-required" ng-model="user.sourceOfFunds" required="" ng-class="{submitted:invalid}">
                <option value="">Select</option>
                <option value="Savings">Deposit</option>
                <option value="Inherited">Current</option>
                <option value="Other">Savings</option>
                        </select>
```

```js
element(by.model('user.sourceOfFunds')).sendKeys('Savings');
```

My other dropdown menu is as follows:

```html
<select class="form-control ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-invalid-required" ng-model="user.investFigure" required="" ng-class="{submitted:invalid}">
                         <option value="">Select</option>
                         <option value="<20">Less than 20K</option>
                         <option value="20-50">20K-50K</option>
                         <option value="50-100">50K-100K</option>
                         </select>
```

```js
element(by.model('user.investFigure')).sendKeys('Less than 20K');
or
element(by.model('user.investFigure')).sendKeys('20');
```

I get "element not found" when I try to select an item from the second drop down menu. I'm at a bit of a loss as to why this is happening

Comment: Are you sure the second dropdown is present on the page at the time you are sending keys to it? Also, what if you would find all of the `select` elements: `$$("select").map(function (elm) { return elm.getAttribute("ng-model"); }).then(console.log);` - do you see both the dropdown models printed? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, when I ran the code you supplied. It only printed elements contained in the user.sourceOfFunds drop down menu

Comment: Great, that explains the error. Let's do a quick test, put `browser.sleep(10000);` before this statement - still no second dropdown model printed?

Comment: I just did that and it didn't print the second dropdown model

Comment: Alright, so, this is not a timing issue and the dropdown is definitely not there. Now, I cannot give you a definitive answer on why the dropdown is not there - please check if it is not an app build problem, or may be you should have done something else in order for dropdown to appear.

Comment: thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Using `sendKeys` to select a dropdown option seems odd to me, even if it works. Given @alecxe's fine suggestions, perhaps the issue is visibility, but try another way and see if `sendKeys` is your issue.

I use this code on tests with multiple selects every day without issue. Maybe it'll work for you...

```
var selectOptionByText = function(text) {
    return element(by.cssContainingText('option', text)).click();
};
```

Call thusly...

```
selectOptionByText('Less than 20');
selectOptionByText('20');
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, the above works when  I use it for the 'Savings' drop down menu but when I use it for selectOptionByText('Less than 20');
selectOptionByText('20'); I get " Element is not currently visible and may not be manipulated"